# Splitting NIFTI images to voxel patches

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, nifti, nibabel

I am trying to split a set 3D MRA NIFTI images into voxel patches of equal sizes (e.g. 32 x 32 x 32).
The goal is to use the voxels to train a 3D CNN to detect anomalies within the cerebral arteries.

How can this be achieved with Python using some library like Numpy.